# How to write text to excel sheet specific column or row through CAPL scripting?

Tags: capl

How to write text to excel sheet specific column or row through CAPL scripting?

The content has to be written on already existing excel sheet on specific location

Answer (score 0):

Only as a scheme for further discussion as CAPL is truly not the best solution to do this:

Step 1. Open your (text) file with *openFileWrite()*

Step 2. Find the place in text where you want to write, 
how would you do this using CAPL?

Step 3. Write text with *filePutString()*

Step 4. Close file *fileClose()*

If it is really necessary to write something into .csv (in worst case into .xls) file during a measurement, than maybe you have to try using a C library instead of hacking CAPL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for extending CAPL to work with Excel sheets. While you might write it yourself, it's probably easier to call some external script in Python (or any other language), which gets your data as arguments and place them into specified excel sheet.

You can execute it with `sysExecCmd()` function.